# Chrome Extension + create-react-app live reload

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, create-react-app

Any advise on how to achieve live-reloading when implementing a Chrome Extension with create-react-app? Currently I `yarn run build` every time there is a change.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to CRX + CRA + hot reload.

Comment: CRA is just not the right tool for extensions. I recommend you use Parcel instead. It has less configuration compared to Webpack. It watches for changes in source code and outputs to build folder, which you will drag to the extensions page and enjoy this hot-reload-like experience.

Comment: @JoãoMarceloSouza do you have an example of ohw to go about that because I couldnt work out how to export your manifest.json using ParcelJS

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do that using create-react-app by:

```
npm i npm-watch --save-dev
```

Then in the package.json

```
{
    "name": "react-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": false,
    "devDependencies": {
        "npm-watch": "^0.1.8",
        "react-scripts": "0.9.5",
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^15.4.2",
        "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "watch": "npm-watch" //add this to the script
    },
    "watch": {  //add this outside the script
        "build": "src/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with `fswatch` on Mac (had to `brew install fswatch`):

```
fswatch -o ~/$PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT/src | xargs -n1 -I{} npm run build
```

This will run `npm run build` anytime the `src` directory changes (which is what I was doing manually beforehand anyways)

Note: my manifest is pointing to the build directory for my popup.

Answer (score 0):

I achieve live-reloading when implementing a Chrome Extension V3 with create-react-app. Whatever you change page or content script, all things is auto refresh/reload.
https://github.com/Godiswill/cra-crx-boilerplate