# Hot/Live reloading for React Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? Currently I have rerun the build every single time to see an update.

I tried the solution linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082288/chrome-extension-create-react-app-live-reload) but it still requires me to manually build each time.

I tried to use this package [Chrome Extension Hot Reload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-extension-hot-reload) but despite copying the code from the site after installing it, it says HotReload is not exported from the package, so I can't even run start or connect.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using WebPack, you can achieve this in a few steps (without installing any special plugins):

In your WebPack config, set your dev server to write files to disk, instead of serving them from memory:

```js
devServer: {
    devMiddleware: {
        writeToDisk: true,
    },
}
```

And set your output to wherever you told Chrome to load your extension from:

```js
output: {
    path: 'path/to/build/',
},
```

Make sure that all the HTML files that you want hot reload are going through WebPack, and not statically copied to the destination folder. You can generate those HTML files with [html-webpack-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/):

```js
entry: {
    index: 'path/to/index.js',
}
plugins: {
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        chunks: ['index'], // Should correspond to the entry point name
    }),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I spend a few days to solve this problem, I created a repo by CRA reject, it works with Manifest V3 and content script.

1. Use HRM of webpack to achieve [hot reloading](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/#via-the-nodejs-api).
2. Use [React-refresh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-refresh) to achieve partial refresh.

create-react-app has done all above.

Finally, Use the communication between background and content，chrome.runtime.reload can reload crx when the content is changed.

Here is a example: [cra-crx-boilerplate](https://github.com/Godiswill/cra-crx-boilerplate)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31848310)

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is no if you use Manifest V3.

It's not dependent on the framework, but more about chrome and how it manages extensions.

You can read a bit more about this here:
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/pYtdXH0f46E?pli=1

Comment: That's unfortunate then. I'm new to Chrome Extension development. For development, should I just endure having to run build every single time, or should I be swapping to Manifest V2 if it worked for that? And if the latter is the case, what's the preferred way enabling live reloading then?

Comment: Having worked on React Chrome extensions before, my recommendation is to use Manifest V3. Upgrading from V2 is a pain and V2 is potentially nearly dead. What I would also recommend, though, is using esbuild to bundle your React application, because it's wayyyy faster than using Webpack, so it's also way less painful.

Comment: i don't recommend downgrading to V2, Chrome will start refuse new app with V2 in 10 days, the 17 January 2022, see timeline there: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv2-sunset/
Next year you will have to upgrade anyway.
I tried to post on twitter to gather more info : https://twitter.com/martindonadieu/status/1479401500518625280?s=20